# Hovering over items in /help/privileges causes underscores to appear

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design, privileges-page

On a Mac OS X 10.11.1 running Firefox 42.0, hovering over an item in https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges causes an underscore to appear before the reputation number, the icon, and the description of the privilege (is this reproduced in other environments?):

[image]

This does not happen on, for example, [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges):

[image]

Is this therefore a bug? If so, can it be fixed?

Comment: I noticed with FF on Linux too already

Comment: I noticed with chromium on Linux too already.

Comment: add chrome/windows and ie11/windows to the list.

Comment: Apparently, none of the web-designers cares about this :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this one as well and sorry it had to wait so long.. I've just pushed fix to repo and it should be live with next build.