# Apparent bug when hovering over pagination items of the /users page on the main site

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On the main site's `/users` page, if you hover over the pagination, there is a line that appears between the items:

[image]

This does not happen on the meta site:

[image]

Nor does it happen on Stack Overflow:

[image]

I assume that this is therefore a bug on the main site.

(For what it's worth, the screenshots are from Firefox, but I can also reproduce this behavior with Google Chrome and Safari.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. I've just pushed fix to repo and it should be live with next build.

Comment: Thanks @Paweł! +1, and I'll accept once the new build is live. Also, is there any chance that you could also take a look at [Hovering over items in /help/privileges causes underscores to appear](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6416/32888). It's a similar bug that has gone unaddressed for almost 2 years now.

Comment: @AdamLiter ok, i've just fixed that too. btw. it was weird for me that this is not fixed yet. i took another look and seems like i made some mistake. So it should be live with next build, but this time for real!

Comment: Thanks @Paweł! Both look to be fixed now.